# How to save command output to specific line of text file

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to know how to save command output to a specific line of a text file.

I searched on the internet for about an hour about this problem, but I didn't find any proper answer.

For example:

I want to save the output of some `ls` command to 7th line of `example.txt`.
(insert new line)

How would I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be what you need: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70878/replacing-string-based-on-line-number

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the existing 7th line? or insert the new line before or after it?

Comment: @steeldriver insert new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sed's `r` command to read and insert the command output after a given address. In particular, GNU sed provides the special filename `/dev/stdin` to read data from standard input.

So for example, given

```
$ cat example.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

then

```
$ ls -l example.txt | sed -i '7r/dev/stdin' example.txt
```

results in

```
$ cat example.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 71 Jun 28 15:52 example.txt
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

If you want the command output inserted *before* the 7th line, then read and insert it after the 6th.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much.